# Eclipse web servers - What is the difference between locations?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I have servers like tomcat and glassfish intalled in my eclipse kepler. When I right click and see properties of any server,
I see a property called location under the general options in eclipse. There is a switch location button next to it. 
I can switch the location to -

1. [Workspace metadata]
2. Installation folder of my web server

What is the difference between these two ? How do I decide which one is better ?

Answer (score 3):

That property indicates where Eclipse is storing the server's configuration metadata. By default, Eclipse hides those details from you, but the button allows you to change it so you can view (or potentially edit) it.

From the Eclipse help pages (http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftmetasrv.html):

> On the workbench, you have the option to display or hide the metadata
> of the server.
>
> The metadata contains a variety of information about the server such
> as:
>
> - The location where the server configuration files are stored on
>   the workbench.
> - The fully qualified DNS name or IP address of the host machine where the server is running.
> - The name assigned to the server.
> - The name of the installed server runtime environment which defines the
>   runtime environment of an application server for compiling your
>   application.
>
> By default, the workbench hides the metadata of the
> server to keep the development workspace clean. Displaying the
> metadata of the server on the workbench, allows you to persist the
> data of the server in a serverName.server file, where serverName is
> the name assigned to the server. The serverName.server file is useful
> when you are working in a team development environment and you are
> required to maintain the metadata of the server in a source control
> repository.
>
> To display or hide the metadata of the server:
>
> 1. In the Servers view,
>    right-click the server you want to display or hide the metadata and
>    select Properties.
> 2. In the General page there is a Location field,
>    select the Switch location button to toggle between displaying and
>    hiding the metadata on the workbench.
>    *Tip: If the value of the Location field contains [workspace metadata], this means the workbench is hiding the metadata. To display the metadata on the workbench,
>    select the Switch location button again until the [workspace metadata]
>    changes to a file path directory. The file path directory specifies
>    the location where the server metadata file is stored on the
>    workbench. The next step describes where you can find the server
>    metadata file in the workbench.*
> 3. In the Project Explorer view, expand
>    the Servers folder and then expand your server project to locate the
>    serverName.server file, where serverName is the name assigned to your
>    server.
> 4. (Optional) You can double-click serverName.server file to edit
>    the data in the server editor.

Comment: `By default, the workbench hides the metadata of the server to keep the development workspace clean.` I am not able to see how that happens. My workspace is always clean and no extra stuff seems to be added when I use actual server installation folder.

Comment: Depending on which type of server you have configured I think there is a different default location for the server configuration. On my Tomcat and tc Server servers, the default config location is a special project in the workspace named **Servers** and switching the location away from `[metadata]` shows a `.server` file in there. Other types of servers (or maybe different choices made when creating the server) might lead to storing the config in a different location that, perhaps, isn't reflected in your workspace.

Comment: Can you pls show some screenshots for comparison ? thx.